# Set a math symbol in italics

Tags: math-mode, tex-core, italic

I have an equation that contains the \inf symbol and which I would like to add it in italics mode. When I add in my latex code the following: `$\inf$` the result is not in italics though. How, can I set this command in italics?

Comment: `\inf` does not produce a "symbol". Instead, it produces the letters `i`, `n`, and `f` in upright (aka "roman") letters. If you looking to typeset the infinity *symbol*, you should be typing `\infty`. In fine math typography, all "operators" -- cf det, ln, log, max, min, sin, cos, tan, sup, exp, etc -- are *always* typeset using upright letters. This is done precisely to help distinguish them from letters that denote variables, which are generally typeset in math-italics.

Comment: Why would you? Traditionally, the “inf” operator is written upright.